# Java Recursive function sometimes working

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I've called upon what I've learned so far and still can't fix this so decided to come here.

A BasicBlock object is referenced by an integer and holds references to the 'addresses' of more blocks in a list. I want to obtain the addresses that they hold reference to and i thought to do this recursively. It is possible for one BasicBlock to hold reference to 0 or more other blocks.

The below recursive function getFunctionReferences keeps returning a stack overflow error, yet manages to work sometimes.

```
Map<Integer,BasicBlock> blockList blockList = new TreeMap<Integer,BasicBlock>();

public HashSet<Integer> getAssociatedAddresses(int function) {
    HashSet<Integer> blockAddresses = new HashSet<Integer>();   
    getFunctionReferences(this.blockList.get(function),blockAddresses);
    return blockAddresses;
}

private void getFunctionReferences(BasicBlock block, HashSet<Integer> blockAddresses){ 
    for (int x : block.getAddressReferenceList()) {  
        blockAddresses.add(x);
        getFunctionReferences(this.blockList.get(x), blockAddresses);
    }
}
```

I know that I am doing something wrong with this call, especially as there is no base case. But I don't know how to deal with recursion when it is in a loop like this....nor do I know a suitable base case.

Help massively appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can store visited addresses and/or references in a set to check, whether you have already visited them. Btw.: there are two blockList in line 1.

Comment: Thanks Eran! I think that is the issue. Is that to say that recursion is unsuitable in this case? How best would one deal with this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have cycles (for example block 1 references block 2 which references block 3 which references block 1), you'll get infinite recursion leading to `StackOverflowError`.

To avoid that, you can take advantage of the `HashSet` of visited blocks which you maintain. You can simply check if a block was already visited and avoid making another recursive call if it was:

```
private void getFunctionReferences(BasicBlock block, HashSet<Integer> blockAddresses){ 
    for (int x : block.getAddressReferenceList()) {  
        if (blockAddresses.add(x)) { // only make a recursive call if x wasn't already
                                     // in the Set
            getFunctionReferences(this.blockList.get(x), blockAddresses);
        }
    }
}
```